# Will SQLite hoist invariant constraints?

Tags: sqlite

I have been looking for solutions of a similar question like

https://forums.asp.net/t/1887910.aspx?Inner+join+2+tables+but+return+all+if+1+table+empty

Someone proposed a solution like the following

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TableA AS a
    LEFT JOIN TableB AS b ON b.A_Id = a.A_Id
WHERE
    b.A_Id IS NOT null
    OR
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 A_Id FROM TableB)
```

Does SQLite run `not exists (select top 1 A_Id from TableB)` for each row? This condition should be the same for all rows. I was wondering if the query engine could hoist it to the very top. Otherwise, it would take a lot of cost.

I tried the following

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
select test.testID, test.name, parameter.name
from test 
left join parameter
on test.testID = parameter.testID 
where 
  parameter.testID is not null 
  or not exists (select testId from    parameter limit 1)
```

It reports

```
 selectid   order   form    detail
 0          0       0       SCAN TABLE test (~1M rows)
 0          1       1       search table parameter using automatic covering index (testID=?) (~ 7 rows)
 0          0       0       EXECUTE SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
 1          0       0       SCAN TABLE parameter (~1M rows)
```

Does it mean SQlite does not hoist `(select testId from    parameter limit 1)`?

Comment: Run an `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` on it to see what it does: https://sqlite.org/eqp.html

Comment: This isn't a "constraint" - it's a correlated-subquery.

Comment: What is this query meant to return? It looks like it should be an `INNER JOIN` though I don't understand what the `NOT EXISTS` subquery is meant to accomplish.

Comment: @Dai, I wanted to inner join A and B. When B is empty, I wanted to get A. Like: https://forums.asp.net/t/1887910.aspx?Inner+join+2+tables+but+return+all+if+1+table+empty

Comment: Does this have to be done in one query? Why not first see if the table is empty and then select either all or the joined data? And is a normal LEFT JOIN not good enough? The difference is just that you will get the non-matching rows even if the other table is not empty. But you can tell if it was a matching row or not.

Comment: @Thilo, I can do either of this. But they need either pre-process or post-process... I had thought SQLite can automatically optimize my query. To me, it seems obvious that we can hoist out the subquery but I know I must overlook some subtle details or corner cases...

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub) says:

> A correlated subquery is reevaluated each time its result is required. An uncorrelated subquery is evaluated only once and the result reused as necessary.

Your subquery is not correlated, because it does not contain references to columns in the outer query. (And the EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN output would show `EXECUTE CORRELATED SCALAR SUBQUERY ...`.)

Comment: Explain query plan shows 'EXECUTE SCALAR SUBQUERY 1', but does not say whether it is correlated or not. And I do not think it is correlated.